# OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' in WebDriver.dll while trying to click on the link

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a simple automation script in C# which will load google homepage then type something in the search box, list the results and then click on the "Images" link and show possible images of the searched item.

I was able to get to the point when Selenium Webdriver is able to locate the Images link by LinkText but when I want to perform a Click() operation I get error message Exception thrown: 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' in WebDriver.dll and I am not able to move further.

I am placing my code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace WebDriverDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Url = "http://www.google.com";

           var searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
           searchBox.SendKeys("apple");
           searchBox.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

           driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));


            try
            {
                var imageLink = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Images"));
                Console.Write("Element found by a LinkText");
                imageLink.Click();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

I am looking forward to your feedback and possible solutions :)

Best regards and thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a brief pause after searching to wait for the Images link to be clickable.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("apple\n");
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.LinkText("Images"))).Click();
```

Also, you can send `\n`, which is a carriage return, as part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a long delay, however I was able to solve the problem myself. Instead of driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Images")) I used the Xpath, to show me the exact location of the image link :)

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why it is so :|
After trying different 'types of waits', only 1 seems to be working:

Thread.Sleep(2000);

Hope this helps for now. I'm still looking for better workaround.